# electrical noise problem with adaptor

Tags: noise

I don't know why, but everytime i or someone on the room next door switch off lamp, there is a loud pop coming from the speaker.

1) is that behaviour are caused by my amplifier (diy)(the line in cable doesn't have shielding,just 3 wire)

2) improper build of electrical installation in the building itself

3) my adaptor is bad? (i think it's just have big cap, resistor and 4 diode and a transfomers,the case is quite transparant though)

And how can i resolve this thing? Because it's quite annoying
the noise is present whether connecting to laptop/phone or not

Comment: Hi, a bit more detail please. Does this happen when the amplifier audio input is connected to a computer, to a phone, or disconnected?

Comment: all of them, connected to anything or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a defective light switch that is arcing internally, causing a whole heap of noise being introduced to the local circuit.

Otherwise, I would investigate some of the suggestions and answers referenced here.
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28049/whats-causing-the-popping-noise-from-my-speakers

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see enough information to rule out any of those, and all should be fixed.  Of the three, only number two is likely to be fatal.  I'd go and buy a 3-wire receptacle tester, and verify your neutral and ground are correct.  You can probably pick one up for $10.  Having these fouled up is dangerous, and will cause noise, among other issues (like death).  If they are bad, get a qualified electrician to make the repairs.

Then, move on to number one, and get a decent shielded cable.  These don't have to be the expensive gold plated (literally) ones.  The lamp switch might be dirty, and causing a little spark.  These are usually well contained within the lamp itself, and aren't dangerous, but the spark can be picked up by the unshielded cable.

Doesn't your "adapter" have a transformer too?  I'd be surprised if it doesn't. I can't think how this might be involved with your noise related to a lamp switch, but you seem uncertain about it, so you might want to replace it.

Good luck!